# Nokogiri cannot exit opening a url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, irb, pry

When I try in pry (which is a substitute for IRB or rails console)

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

It reads the file (although I have to keep pressing space bar). However, at the end, it says

```
(END)
```

and it doesn't return the command line back to me.

What do I need to do to exit this and get back to the prompt?

Comment: Nokogiri isn't opening the file. Open::URI is, which then passes the read content to Nokogiri as a StringIO object. Pry then displays the result of the parse. If you're seeing the display pause it's because PRY is paging the output since neither Open::URI or Nokogiri does paging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type `q` to exit less viewer. the result of Nokogiri::HTML is too long so you are seeing result bypassing less command